# It says on the desktop that I'm using DreamStudio but I'm not

Tags: lsb-release, 15.10

I've just started to notice this. I'm using Wily Werewolf at the moment, and has been working fine. I have done some tests to make sure that I'm actually using Wily, like checking the Unity version (7.3.2) and gnome-terminal version (3.16.2).

But, weirdly enough, when I click on the show desktop icon, at the top it says `DreamStudio Desktop`. I've have never installed DreamStudio before!
On top of that, when I go to the terminal and type `lsb_release -a`, it says `DreamStudio 14.04.2 LTS` as the distribution, and `precise` as the release code name!

Please help me, this has never happened before.

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:
Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted multiverse

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security universe

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner
```

Edit 2:
Output of `grep -r dreamstudio /etc/apt`
Could be the cause of this error, but only just started showing these errors that, and tried I did *try* installing DreamStudio, but never got to the stage where I was writing changes.

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dreamstudio-ubuntu-dreamstudio-stable-wily.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dreamstudio/dreamstudio-stable/ubuntu trusty main
```

Edit 3:
Output of `apt-cache policy base-files`

```
base-files:
  Installed: 7.2ubuntu11
  Candidate: 7.2ubuntu11
  Version table:
 *** 7.2ubuntu11 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Edit 4: Output of `apt-cache policy unity`

```
unity:
  Installed: 7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 7.3.2+15.10.20151016-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Edit 5: Output of `dpkg -l 'language-pack-gnome*'`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-=========================================================================
ii  language-pack-gnome-en             1:15.10+20151016       all                    GNOME translation updates for language English
ii  language-pack-gnome-en-base        1:15.10+20151016       all                    GNOME translations for language English
un  language-pack-gnome-zh-base                                          (no description available)
un  language-pack-gnome-zh-hant                                          (no description available)
rc  language-pack-gnome-zh-hant-base   1:14.04+20140707       all                    GNOME translations for language Traditional Chinese
```

Edit 6: Output of `apt-cache policy language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base`

```
language-pack-gnome-en:
  Installed: 1:15.10+20151016
  Candidate: 1:15.10+20151016
  Version table:
 *** 1:15.10+20151016 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
language-pack-gnome-en-base:
  Installed: 1:15.10+20151016
  Candidate: 1:15.10+20151016
  Version table:
 *** 1:15.10+20151016 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy base-files` say?

Comment: The latest DreamStudio release was Precise. Interesting.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r 'dreamstudio' /etc/apt`

Comment: @A.B. There seems to be a PPA of DreamStudio for trusty and an abandoned domain. I'm not sure if PPA/SourceForge and Distrowatch entry are actually related.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Well the PPA seems to provide the packages that come with DreamStudio.

Comment: It is clear that you installed the system from a 13.10 image, and later upgraded, at some point adding the DreamStudio PPAs, which would have resulted in such possible changes. You need to purge the PPAs and `apt-get install --reinstall` anything that would have come from them.

Comment: And why have you upgraded to Xenial?

Comment: @A.B Is there a reason I can't?

Answer (score 0):

If you or someone else installed DreamStudio through [dreamstudio.sh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dreamstudio/files/Celeum_DreamStudio_2015/Celeum%20DreamStudio%20Ubuntu/) or [its PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dreamstudio/+archive/ubuntu/dreamstudio-stable) then it could install and overwrite `/etc/lsb-release` from the package `base-files`.

Comment: OP has never installed DreamStudio.

Comment: @Jos Okay, that just tells us this much: Someone or something did this.

Comment: Okay, OP *tried* to install DreamStudio, as it now appears.

Comment: @Jos Notice I said that no changes were made to the actual system